# Does the AI recommend founding a city on resources?

Tags: civilization-5

When founding cities in Civilization V in early game it might happen that you places them on iron, coal, oil or uranium. This is extremely annoying, especially with rare resources. 
If I'm sticking to the AI's recommendations, will I ever found cities on such resources?

Comment: Why's it annoying? Putting a city on a resource gives you that resource automatically.

Comment: @Michaellogg This is not how I like it ;)

Comment: Yeh, it's *much* better when your rare & valuable resources are susceptible to pillage & siege.  Though if you're *expecting* to loose the city, being able to deny *their* citizens access could be a bonus.

Comment: The benefits of immediately having the resource and without needing to construct a building to access it saves time and resources in game.

Comment: @ the commenters here: For a Civ4-player it's anathema to found on a resource tile, because developed resources grant much higher yield than undeveleoped. In Civ 5 this bonus is sginificantly smallerm aking founding resources an ok trade off for the security of the resource. Still ,you won't see a long-term Civ-Player wanting to found on a resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, why would it?

From any logical point of view, you have no way of knowing in 3000 BC, that you are settling on an uranium deposit.

On top of that, you can frequently see the AI settle on Resources and the AI recommendation works on the same algorithm.